# Train ML.net on dataset of images and text description

Tags: asp.net, ml.net, ml.net-model-builder

I have developed an ASP.NET solution to train ML.NET using a combination of malfunction and normal images. The images are stored in a single folder, each with a corresponding name. Additionally, I have a .csv file with multiple columns, including "image_NM," "Description," and "Malfunction." The "Malfunction" column specifies whether each image exhibits a malfunction (Yes/No).

To enable the module to determine whether a newly uploaded image contains a malfunction, I need to train it on both the images and the associated .csv files. Could you please provide guidance on how to accomplish this?